# How to add 2 toast message in 1 java class?

Tags: java, android, android-toast

I am trying to add another `Toast` message for my application, I've already made the first one when data is empty `Toast` message pop up and say " Sorry data still empty" and I would like make another one message pop up when there is data is available like "Data successfully loaded".

**Here is my code:**

```
if (gamename.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(spk_activity.this,"Sorry Data Still Empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: else Toast.makeText(spk_activity.this,"Data succesfully loaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Where is the code for your second `Toast` and what *exactly* is the problem?

Comment: Simply do it in else part.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write another code in your activity. Like below

> if (gamename.isLoaded()){ Toast.makeText(spk_activity.this,"Data succesfully   loaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();